# In Azure Functions, how to use route parameter inside an output binding

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

Below is an http triggered function. For the route, I have specified a variable `user`. Now, I want this variable `user` to be consumed in *any other* output binding. **Now working** code shown with `Blob` as an output binding.

```
[FunctionName(nameof(Greeting))]
public static IActionResult Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "{user}/greeting")] HttpRequest req,
string user,
[Blob("{user}", Connection = "MyStorageAccount")] CloudBlockBlob blob)
    => new OkResult();
```

N.B. I'm not actually interested in creating a blob. Just interested in the syntax that works.

Edit: Just realising that this works perfectly.

Comment: There is no problem with the grammar. Have you face any problems?

Comment: thanks, you are right. this code sample is already working. my only excuse now for posting this question is that it wan't working before :p

Comment: Hi, If you dont have any more questions, can you mark my answer to end this question? Thanks.:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, off course.

Have a look of this structure:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp32
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "GetName/{name}")] HttpRequest req,
            string name,
            [Blob("sample-images-sm/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream imageSmall,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            //string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

If written like this, locally, if you send a message like `http://localhost:7071/api/GetName/Bowman`, then the string name will be Bowman and function will create a container named sample-images-sm and a Bowman file under this container.

This is the Offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp